# CTPageMar values unit?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I am using apache poi CTPageMar class to set a page margin to some value given by the user.
The problem is that I did not find what is the unit of the values that must be passed in the functions setLeft,setRight,setTop and setBottom.
I tried cm, pixels, inches but they all seem wrong.
Any idea?

```
XWPFDocument wordDocument = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(input));
CTSectPr sectPr = wordDocument.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
CTPageMar pageMar = sectPr.addNewPgMar();
pageMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(left));
pageMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(top));
pageMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(right));
pageMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(bottom));
wordDocument.write(new FileOutputStream(output));
```

Comment: If you set a known value in Word, then read it back in Apache POI, what do you see?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The measure unit is Twip (twentieth of an inch point). One twip is 1/1440 inch. So

```
...
  int twipsPerInch =  1440;
  pageMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(1 * twipsPerInch));
...
```

will be 1 inch left margin.